# Need work around for URL based List button on Lightning

Tags: lightning, urlhacking

We are migrating to Lightning and we are replacing URL based 'List Button' on Opportunity related list under Accounts. We want to pre-default standard 'Opportunity Name' field with 'Account Name' value. SF suggests 'Quick Actions' which cannot be mapped on Opportunity related list. Is there any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a quick action to create the Opp and set default field values in the quick action.  Then you'd have to remove the default "New" button from the related list.  The quick action could be added to the other actions in the top right corner of the Account page.

Comment: Yup that action is already added. But is there a way to add it as list button? I mean, we need it on Related list.

Comment: Currently there is no way to add custom actions to related lists in Lightning.  You can  vote for the idea here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003TXFQA2